# did onomatopoeia create verbs?

Tags: etymology

I have a brother who says that the onomatopoeia has created verbs, like, for example, the verb knock was invented because the onomatopoeia did say so. but I think it is the other way around, that first was the verb and then the onomatopoeia. Who has the reason?

Comment: Well, ducks are not copying humans when they **quack**, nor did trees develop such that wooden doors would give the **knock** sound.

Comment: Your brother is right that onomatopoeia inspired words. Stretching your opinion, I could say that after I hear that Yiddish calls it *pishing* not pissing, I can also say, "Oh, yeah, I can hear it as *pish*." But that would come after the word was coined, and naming came after its sound to the ears of those speakers.

Comment: "first was the verb and then the onomatopoeia"? How does ***that*** work?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm having trouble understanding it too! It's a perfect example of the tail wagging the dog.

Comment: @TonyK: Actually, I have occasionally heard people articulate something suggested by the orthography ***Tsk**!* And even more often, ***Tut [-tut]**!* Neither of which are anything like the sound those orthographies are *supposed* to represent (a brief suck of air into the roof of the mouth as a sign of exasperation). Then there's the dated (primarily, *children's*) slang usage ***Pip, pip**!*, which I suspect was originally the rapid double click made by doing something similar with the *side* of the tongue (equivalent to ***Giddy-up**!*, addressed to your horse).

Comment: Although lacking in research, this Q is interesting, and undeserving of off-the-cuff VTC/

Comment: @Cascabel _Onomatopoeia_'s **definition**, according to [[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/onomatopoeia)],  is ' the naming of a thing or action by a vocal imitation of the sound associated with it (such as buzz, hiss)', so research is non-optional here. If this definition is accepted, the question is needless.

Comment: I have edited the tag as this has nothing to do with American English. OED: Knock - **Etymology**: Late Old English *cnocian*, beside usual West Saxon *cnucian*; compare Old Norse *knoka*; **probably of echoic origin**.